# Webgrid: Maintain Filter after Sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

I have set up a webgrid and it seems to work fine, allowing me to sort and page. I have added a filter option which also works well however if I filter and *then* sort the results, the filter is lost and all records are displayed.

Here is my Razor view code:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "myGrid" }))
{

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Document Search</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Enter a Document code:")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Editor("search")
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(null, rowsPerPage: 10, canPage: true, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "myGrid");
    grid.Bind(Model, autoSortAndPage: true);
}

<div id="myGrid">

    @grid.GetHtml(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, firstText: "First Page", nextText: "Next", previousText: "Previous", lastText: "Last Page", numericLinksCount: 10,
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("DocumentID", "Document Code", canSort: true),
                grid.Column("Title", "Document Title", canSort: true)
        )
    )

</div>
```

And here is my action:

```
public ActionResult Index(string search)
    {
        List<DocumentIndexViewModel> viewModel = Mapper.Map<List<DocumentIndexViewModel>>(DocumentService.GetDocumentsBySearch(search));
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView("_IndexGrid", viewModel);
        else
            return View(viewModel);
    }
```

How do I maintain the filter when I sort the displayed records? It seems like I need to append the search string onto the sort links somehow but am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using GET for the filter this should preserve it. I am unable to reproduce the problem. Here's my full working test case.

Model:

```
public class CityViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string search)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
            query["q"] = search;
            var json = client.DownloadString("http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?" + query.ToString());
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var viewModel = serializer
                .Deserialize<string[]>(json)
                .Select((x, index) => new CityViewModel
                {
                    Id = index,
                    Name = x
                })
                .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(search ?? string.Empty, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                .ToList();

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_IndexGrid", viewModel);
            }
            else
            {
                return View(viewModel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main view (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model IEnumerable<CityViewModel>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "gridPartial" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Document Search</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Enter a Document code:")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.Editor("search")
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div id="gridPartial">
    @Html.Partial("_IndexGrid")
</div>
```

`~/Views/Home/_IndexGrid.cshtml` partial:

```
@model IEnumerable<CityViewModel>

@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(null, rowsPerPage: 10, canPage: true, canSort: true, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "myGrid");
    grid.Bind(Model, autoSortAndPage: true);
}

<div id="myGrid">
    @grid.GetHtml(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, firstText: "First Page", nextText: "Next", previousText: "Previous", lastText: "Last Page", numericLinksCount: 10,
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Id", "City Id", canSort: true),
            grid.Column("Name", "City Name", canSort: true)
        )
    )
</div>
```

Sorting and pagination preserves the search filter that was entered because it was in the query string.

Comment: Are you saying the sorting header links in the grid have the search string in the href? Mine just seem to have a '#'.

Comment: Don't look at your browser address bar. Look at what's actually sent to the server. Analyze the exact request being sent with AJAX. It contains the search query string parameter. So the filter is not stored in the href of the links at all. Those links have `onclick` javascript events associated to them which trigger an AJAX request sending the search criteria properly to the server.

Comment: In that case then, do I need to just pull the value out of the request in the controller action?

Comment: Strange, it now appears to be working, passing in the search string to the action when I sort the webgrid. However when I follow a link to another page and then use the browser back button, it loses the filter. Infact worse than this, IE displays an older version of the webpage which was modified hours ago! So how do I preserve the filter when navigating back?

Comment: That's the browse back button problem. There's not much you could do about it. You have no control over this button. As a possible workaround provide a link on the other page so that the user could navigate back by passing the filter as query string parameter.